# Git checkout each commit

Tags: github

I need to download each github commit of a specific project so as to analyze it with sonarqube. 
 
The problem is to checkout a specific file without removing two files from the root directory (I need those files for the sonarqube configuration)

I tried to run the following piece of code but I have problems with the git checkout.

Both git reset and git checkout return the same error: 
"error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:"
        ...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

How can I force the checkout of a specific commit?

```
#!/bin/bash

git log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad %H" | awk '{ x = $0 "\n" x } END { printf "%s", x }' >commits.txt

IFS=" "
while read f1 f2 
    do       
        git checkout -f $f2
        sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectDate=$f1   
    done < commits.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stash your changes:

```
git stash save
```

Do your update

```
git checkout -f $f2
```

Unstash your changes

```
git stash pop
```

Perform analysis...